# send push notification with parse to single device

Tags: android, parse-platform

**Can I send a push-message within my android app to only one certain device** (probably with the device id ?) instead of to every device?
a simple "yes, that's possible with parse" or "no, you can't use parse for that" will be enough!
if ans is yes then  I  need to know how.....

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can save a device id in `ParseInstallation` and then target this installation:

**Receiver:**

```
ParseInstallation installation = ParseInstallation.getCurrentInstallation();
installation.put("device_id", "1234567890");
installation.saveInBackground();
```

**Sender:**

```
ParseQuery query = ParseInstallation.getQuery(); 
query.whereEqualTo("device_id", "1234567890");    
ParsePush push = new ParsePush();
push.setQuery(query);
push.sendPushInBackground();
```

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK you will need to add the IP of the sending device/server in google console as trusted - so no, you usually do not use the client to send push to other devices. Instead, send the message to your server, which has all the registered devices to your GCM token, and let the server push the message to the specific client.

You should read the documentation http://developer.android.com/google/gcm/index.html

Comment: i want to send message from on android device to other device.. i am storing  device id on parse.... yes i want to send only text message

Comment: You need to have a server that proxies the message. If you do not want this you should consider using text messaging instead.

Answer (score 0):

Device Id is the way to go. If you want to send to a specific user, create an additional field in your pasrse installation and save the userid on this field. So that you can send to the specific user by filtering with userid and setting the query to get that specific user in the code for sending push.

```
ParseQuery query = ParseInstallation.getQuery(); 
query.whereEqualTo("device_id", "1234567890");   
query.equalTo("user_obj","your_user_object_here");
ParsePush push = new ParsePush();
push.setQuery(query);
push.sendPushInBackground();
```

Comment: Can you please give me some code ...Should i write anything from receiver end?