# Send device to device push notification using parse.com

Tags: android, parse-platform, push-notification

I am new to parse. I have created an android application in which I have to send the push notification by click on the send button. I have successfully stored data to its parse database like Object Id, device type, device token, push type (which is created by default under the installation class).

I have also add some custom column under installation class like age, friend id, gender and retrieve the correspondence Object id in the edit text.
But when I try to send push notification by click on send button, I usually get this error:

```
com.parse.Parse Exception: Clients aren't allowed to perform the find operation on the installation collection
```

The query which I am using to send push notification with object-id corresponding to the given Friend-id is:

```html
  sndpush.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
   
   
   @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
   @Override
   public void onClick(View v) {
    
    JSONObject obj;
    try {
     obj =new JSONObject();
     obj.put("alert","erwerwe");
     obj.put("action","com.parse.pushnotifications.UPDATE_STATUS");
     obj.put("customdata","My string");
     
     ParsePush push = new ParsePush();
     ParseQuery query = ParseInstallation.getQuery();
     query.whereEqualTo("objectId",objectidEditText.getText().toString() );
     
     push.setQuery(query);
     push.setData(obj);
     push.sendInBackground(); 
    }
    catch (JSONException e) 
    {
     
     e.printStackTrace();
    }
    
   }
  });
```

I do google and R&D and I get the idea that we have no permission to send push by get the object id from default class that is installation class.

I have created a new class in parse.com where I have insert some data like age, friend-id and also able to retrieve object-id corresponding to friend id. But when ever I tried to send push notification by supplying Object-id in it, I get the error:

`java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Can only push to a query for Installations`

Here is the code:

```html
// Get the user's Id from parse.com.
  @SuppressWarnings({ "rawtypes", "unchecked" })
  public void getObjectId() {

   @SuppressWarnings("rawtypes")
   ParseQuery query = new ParseQuery("_installation");
   query.whereEqualTo("FriendId", FrndTextString);
   query.getFirstInBackground(new GetCallback() {
    public void done(ParseObject object, ParseException e) {
     if (object == null) {
      Log.d("objectId", "The getFirst request failed.");
     } else {
      String objectid = object.getObjectId();
      objectidEditText.setText(objectid);
      sndpush.setEnabled(true);
      Log.d("objectId", "Retrieved the object.");
     }
    }
   });


  }
```

I have followed the link from stack overflow to send push notification to a specific user. But there is no proper result.

[send push notification with parse to single device](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22533406/send-push-notification-with-parse-to-single-device)

Please tell me where I am wrong. My main question is how can I send a push notification from one device to another.

Here is my complete code:

http://piratepad.net/ep/pad/view/ro.WwZ9v6FX1a6/latest